# I have 2 firefox profiles and a custom shortcut. Why cant firefox open PDF on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, pdf

`"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P "default" -no-remote`

The problem is when I choose firefox to open my PDF, it starts the profile dialog wizard, to choose a profile, while firefox is already opened. It doesn't open my PDF.

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you are attempting to use a specific profile to open a PDF file that isn't going to work. Why can't you set Firefox as the default PDF handler and set the default profile to the profile you want to use to open PDFs?

Comment: Why don't you use a PDF reader, such as Foxit Reader?

Comment: Verify that in Firefox, under `Preferences | General | Applications`, PDF is set to `Preview in Firefox`.

Comment: @harrymc because firefox already lets you read PDF, why would I add software I don't need? Not to mention the trust issues I could have with a third party software.

Comment: I have been using Foxit Reader for many years and fully trust it, me and millions of other users. The Firefox viewer is very basic, fails on some documents, and very slow on large ones.

Comment: well it's off topic and we can disagree. good bye.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, `-no-remote` means your open instance of Firefox will not be used by anything else, which is why when you open a PDF file, Firefox behaves as if it isn't already open. If you're still unsure about the consequences of using `-no-remote`, check out the [documentation for all the command-like arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options).

Is there a reason why you think you need to use `-no-remote`? If not, just omit it and configure your `profiles.ini` to open "default" as the default profile. If there's a reason, we need more info.